# A simple makefile in C - Object file with different name from C file

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile for my program (a very simple one).
My files are `lab.c` and `lab.h`.
I need to create object file of `lab.c` and with a different name (`matlib.o`), and compile without linkage.

This is my attempt:

```
matlib: matlib.o lab.o
    gcc -c matlib.o
matlib.o: lab.c lab.h
    gcc -c lab.c
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
 No rule to make target 'matlib.o', needed by 'matlib'. Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `-o` flag of gcc to set the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell gcc to output the object file in a different name with `-o` flag.

The correct recipe is

```
matlib: matlib.o lab.o
    gcc matlib.o -o matlib
matlib.o: lab.c lab.h
    gcc -c lab.c -o matlib.o
```

Comment: The linker recipe here is very wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist, corrected

Comment: OK but I doubt this is right.  Why is lab.c compiled into matlib.o, and why is the prerequisite on both matlib.o and also lab.o?  However, the question has similarly most-likely-incorrect makefile, so.